# Terminology: What's a mask and what's a flag

Tags: bit-manipulation

I didn't have an education in programming, I learned on my own. But what I couldn't find on the internet is what's the difference between a flag and a mask.

I understand the logic of bitwise operators, I just don't understand the terminology.

for example:

```
int READ_BIT_POSITION = 0x1; // is this a mask?
int WRITE_BIT_POSITION = 0x2; // is this a mask?
int bits = //..// // is this a flag (or flags)?

int read = bits & READ_BIT_POSITION; // or is this a flag?
```

Sorry for this noob question.

Comment: Masks are used to read or modify bits in a word or a bit-field (often but not exclusively when the individual bits are themselves thought of as flags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A flag is usually a single bit in a word.

A mask is typically one or more bits which are used to remove other bits from a word.

There may be some overlap, e.g. in some cases a single bit may be used as either a flag or a mask. However a mask with more than one bit set could not be described as a flag.

In your example:

```
int read = bits & READ_BIT_POSITION;
```

`READ_BIT_POSITION` is being used as a single bit *mask* which will result in `read` containing a 1 bit *flag* extracted from `bits` (and excluding any other bits that it might contain).

Answer (score 1):

A mask defines bits in a value that you are interested in (or not interested in). A flag is one or more bits in that value that represent SOMETHING.

You use masks to read/write the flag values. e.g. If you were painting words on a wall, the mask is the paper stencil you use to mark where the characters go, and the flag is the exact characters you want painted on the wall.

Comment: A flag is always a single bit, usually representing some condition.